# How to "simulate" a Ref?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 component in which `setup()` I defined the following function:

```
const writeNote(note: Ref<Note>) => { console.log(`note ${note.id}` }
```

It receives a `Ref<Note>`, and `Note` is an Interface.

This function is called on two occasions:

- in `<template>` from an event of a component (`@modified-note='writeNote'`), so what is passed to the function is a **reference**
- in a function in `setup()` that retrieves elements of type `Note` and passes them to `writeNote`. What is passed in that case is a **"naked" variable"** (not a reference)

**How can I solve this contradiction?**

- in the call in the template, by somehow "un-referring" what is being sent? (in which case I would modify the type of the argument in the function to a bare `Note`)
- in the call in the function in `setup()`, by somehow turning a normal variable into a reference for the sake of this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vue's [`unref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#unref):

```
const writeNote(_note: Ref<Note> | Note) => { 
  const note = unref(_note);

  console.log(`note ${note.id}`);
}
```

Either that or you will have to create a reactive variable when passing to `writeNote` as you have described in your question. This solution is a bit cleaner but requires you to change `writeNote`'s signature and inners of the function